# Entity framework migrations, domain outside mvc4, SimpleMembership

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-migrations, simplemembership

I like having the domain outside of MVC4. Hence my migrations folder is in domain project.

As everyone else I would like to seed table created by web security using:
http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2012/08/31/seeding-membership-amp-roles-in-asp-net-mvc-4.aspx

Tables created by SimpleMembershipProvider are not exposed to my dbContext and the only way of seeding these tables is by using the code from the link. Obviously this code won't work in my domain project.

Does having domain project outside MVC4 when using migration means that I can't use SimpleMembershipProvider anymore? Or is there a neat way of combining these 3 things together?

Sorry if that is a bit silly question as I just moved to MVC4. Thanks

Comment: There are some tricks you can probably do to make SimpleMembership work with your domain but you probably need to share more information to get a useful answer. Is your domain tightly integrated with user membership information or is it totally separate? Are you planning on using OAth. What are you seeding and how important is it? Is the seeding just for unit test or is it required for production? In my opinion if there is a lot of extension and integration required for membership and role information you are better off creating your own custom membership and role providers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same problem and the solution that I come up with is to expose a seed event in the configurator and let the application subscribe the SimpleMembership seeding with it.

First, the Configuration:

```
    internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<MyContext>
    {
        public event EventHandler<MyContext> OnSeed; 

        public Configuration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
        }

        protected override void Seed(MyContext context)
        {
            var onSeed = this.OnSeed;
            if (onSeed != null)
                onSeed(this, context);

            //  This method will be called after migrating to the latest version.

            //  You can use the DbSet<T>.AddOrUpdate() helper extension method 
            //  to avoid creating duplicate seed data. E.g.
            //
            //    context.People.AddOrUpdate(
            //      p => p.FullName,
            //      new Person { FullName = "Andrew Peters" },
            //      new Person { FullName = "Brice Lambson" },
            //      new Person { FullName = "Rowan Miller" }
            //    );
            //
        }
    }
```

Then, to be able to use it with Database.SetInitializer, I created my own IDatabaseInitializer, based on the MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion. It was easy to do because, as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12392722/entity-framework-migrators-connection) says (and you can check [here](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/7fb31c1526d0#src/EntityFramework/MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion%60.cs)), it is just a wrapper around DbMigration.

```
public class MyDatabaseInitializer : IDatabaseInitializer<MyContext>
{
    private readonly Configuration config;

    public event EventHandler<MyContext> OnSeed
    {
        add { if (this.config != null) this.config.OnSeed += value; }
        remove { if (this.config != null) this.config.OnSeed -= value; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Initializes a new instance of the MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion class.
    /// </summary>
    public MyDatabaseInitializer()
    {
        this.config = new Configuration();
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Initializes a new instance of the MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion class that will
    ///     use a specific connection string from the configuration file to connect to
    ///     the database to perform the migration.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="connectionStringName"> The name of the connection string to use for migration. </param>
    public MyDatabaseInitializer(string connectionStringName)
    {
        Contract.Requires(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(connectionStringName));

        this.config = new Configuration
                      {
                          TargetDatabase = new DbConnectionInfo(connectionStringName)
                      };
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public void InitializeDatabase(MyContext context)
    {
        var migrator = new DbMigrator(config);
        migrator.Update();
    }
}
```

In this initializer I expose the OnSeed event publically. In the App_Start, in the MVC project, I subscribe to it to seed the SimpleMembership data.

```
var initializer = new PoipDatabaseInitializer();
initializer.OnSeed += (s, e) => SeedSecurity();
Database.SetInitializer(initializer);


private static void SeedSecurity()
    {
        WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("MyDatabase", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: false);

        if (!Roles.RoleExists("SysAdmin"))
            Roles.CreateRole("SysAdmin");

        if (!WebSecurity.UserExists("sysadmin"))
            WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(
                "sysadmin",
                "password"
            );

        if (!Roles.GetRolesForUser("sysadmin").Contains("SysAdmin"))
            Roles.AddUsersToRoles(new[] { "sysadmin" }, new[] { "SysAdmin" });
    }
```

Comment: Hi Arthur, thanks for looking at this. I need to admit I found solution to this problem but was too busy (lazy) to update this. I just recreated SimpleMembership Schema as per this link (be aware that correct schema is given in the comment). As for your solution, I'm not good enough to say it's OK. I'll post my solution and after 6 months I will mark the one with more upvotes, what do you say? Or maybe there will be a third one? But your solution is very interesting.

Comment: As I said, I'm facing this issue and I just came up with this solution. I will observe how it will work and its caveats, if there are any, as the project is still under development. I really would like to take a look on yours or any other ones available! I also included the SimpleMembership tables in my model (http://blog.spontaneouspublicity.com/including-asp-net-simple-membership-tables-as-part-of-your-entity-framework-model), but I decided to let the SimpleMembership seed its data with the proper methods, as I'm not sure if it modifies anything other than the expected tables.